# Suggestions for creating an in-house marketing campaign database in a Microsoft environment?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, bids, datamart

I'd like to create an in-house solution to store marketing segment, list, campaign, and communication data.  Right now nothing is centralized/standardized.  Data is located on a variety of SQL servers, Access databases, and Excel spreadsheets.  It's been a real pain when it comes to reporting/tracking.

I'm in a Microsoft SQL Server environment and have access to:

- Microsoft Access
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
- Microsoft Business Intelligence Development Studio

Security and compliance is pretty restrictive in my environment.  Purchasing a third party software package doesn't appear to be an option.  I may have the possibility of having a SQL server sandbox environment created for my use.

I'm curious what suggestions you would recommend and why.  I need to think about all aspects including existing data retrieval/parsing (some on a continuing basis), data import into the new marketing datamart, and reporting.  Some kind of GUI may be required as there isn't currently one for tracking/categorizing much of the data.  One other individual may need access to help with regular imports to help spread workload.

Thanks.

Comment: Peeling home-brewed Excel and Access away from their inventors is hard.  Everyone who builds their own MS-Access toy to store marketing segment, list, campaign, and communication data will be absolutely sure theirs is far, far better than yours could ever be.  How will you deal with folks who don't want your help?

Comment: That has indeed been an issue for us, S.Lott.  I'm hoping that if I can demonstrate ease of use and enough benefits, it could help overcome any fears.  In fact, we may need to run in conjunction for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements are incomplete:

> existing data retrieval/parsing (some on a continuing basis),
>
> data import into the new marketing datamart, and reporting.
>
> Some kind of GUI may be required as there isn't currently one for tracking/categorizing much of the data.
>
> One other individual may need access to help with regular imports to help spread workload.

Here's your question: "I'm curious what suggestions you would recommend and why"

Here's the answer.

1. Who will use this?  Exactly who?  Call every single one of them and talk to them about what they do.
2. What is the business value?  "solution to store marketing segment, list, campaign, and communication data" is a bad idea.  No one wants a "solution" -- they want to get their jobs done.  Few people have "problems"  that need "solutions".  They are already perfectly able to do their job.   The best you can do is make them more efficient.  Do they care about their personal efficiency?  I doubt it.
3. Who has the problem?  What problem do they have?

   Think of a "Bacon and Eggs Breakfast".  The chicken lays an egg and walks away.  The pig, however, is totally committed to the bacon.

   Find the pigs and chickens.  Your data is not going to identify your actors and your business problem.  Find the people who have the problem.  Find out how big and costly the problem is.  Be absolutely sure, you've found the **real** problem that is costing someone **real** money.  Cozy up to the person who's losing the most money and make sure they want their problem solved.  They are the pig -- they can be totally committed.
4. Eventually, you'll want to build one central SQL/Server database and get rid of Excel Spreadsheets and MS-Access databases.  You might want to have an MS-Access front-end which provides nice applications that use SQL/Server.

---

If you are actually talking about a data warehouse, then you must next read books by Ralph Kimball.  [It's not clear, BTW, that a data warehouse is even relevant.  With no problem to solve and no user who has the problem, a data warehouse is just as bad an idea as a web services framework or a new Bentley for me (Black and Silver, thank you.)

If you want to build a data warehouse, your "existing data retrieval/parsing" and "data import into the new marketing datamart" will called **ETL**.

Your "and reporting" will be moved from an "oh, by the way" to the central most important feature of whatever it is you're doing.

Your "Some kind of GUI" will go away.  Data warehousing is not much of a GUI thing.  Reporting is as close as you get.  Maybe you'll have to create some Master Data Management tools, but even then, those are more rules than interactions.

"One other individual may need access"  Really?  The end users are what?  Chopped liver?  They need query access, too, or they won't see any of your data.

Comment: Appreciate the comments.  This is the reason I ask.  The goal is to enable us to do more with our data and increase marketing efficiency.  We'd like to be more proactive.  It can be tough when data is located across disparate systems.  Right now we have no easy way of knowing who has previously received direct mail or email.  I'd like to start small for my own use and demonstrate value.  I'm thinking that would involve simply storing who is sent what.  It could be done with every campaign.  Ideally, this "loading" access would be granted to the other user I mentioned in the future.

Comment: @MattB: You still don't have a "pig" identified.  Who has the problem?  What problem do they have?

Comment: Right now I have the problem and am currently doing things manually that could be automated/better tracked.  However, I'd wager others also have the same problem, but may not realize it.  I'm not in a position to change a large-scale process currently, but am able to begin small with at least a sandbox in SQL Server.  My primary technical question would be in relation to a controlled process that parses specific data and in turn imports it into the sandbox.  Perhaps this is what BIDS could be used for.

Answer (score 3):

You indicate that a purchase of third party software is not an option, however, you should consider that the purchase may in fact be cheaper than the in house development effort, and may bring you to a working system much faster, with less in house skills required.

Comment: No kidding!  No offense to the asker, but based on the question itself, there is a lot of learning needed before even knowing where to start...  A project like this requires planning, and a rock solid knowledge of the tools/options available before you can even plan it on paper, much less code it.

Comment: I agree.  In this case, I'd like to start small and simple to begin demonstrating value by at least tracking who receives which communications.  This isn't meant to be a large-scale project at this point.  I'd like to see where it leads.  Thanks for the comments.